# Zpool list showing blank values

Tags: storage, solaris, zfs, nexenta, zpool

My problem is that when I call `zpool list` it gives this blank output....

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
-         -      -      -      -      -       -  -
```

However a `zfs list` shows that syspool is imported

```
NAME                     USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
syspool                 10.4G  4.15G  35.5K  legacy
syspool/.nza-reserve      31K  4.25G    31K  none
syspool/dump            5.59G  4.15G  5.59G  -
syspool/rootfs-nmu-004   186K  4.15G   850M  legacy
syspool/rootfs-nmu-005  91.5K  4.15G   858M  legacy
syspool/rootfs-nmu-006  97.5K  4.15G   872M  legacy
syspool/rootfs-nmu-007   192M  4.15G   913M  legacy
syspool/rootfs-nmu-008  26.7M  4.15G  1007M  legacy
syspool/rootfs-nmu-009   104K  4.15G   919M  legacy
syspool/rootfs-nmu-010  3.32G  4.15G  1.63G  legacy
syspool/rootfs-nmu-011  81.5K  4.15G   964M  legacy
syspool/swap            1.03G  5.18G    16K  -
syspool/zvol             103M  4.25G    16K  -
```

also backed up by `zpool status`

```
  pool: syspool
 state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        syspool     ONLINE       0     0     0
          c1d0s0    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

If I import a second pool and run a `zpool list` again...

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
-         -      -      -      -      -       -  -
-         -      -      -      -      -       -  -
```

This is causing problems in Nexentastor. NMV's create-dataset page will crash because it uses zpool list output to display current pools. Here is the error...

```
NZAObjectNotFound: ("Volume '-' does not exist"...
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Comment: Never seen this... Can you fill us in on the details of what happened *before* this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by the latest version of libzfs. I rolled back to previous version of the library which cured the issue.

Comment: Based on what? How did you end up with a bad version of `libzfs`? Where did you import the pool from?